# Lista Encadeada em C - Como implementa função inserção

Tags: c

Eu estou tentando implementar dados em uma lista encadeada. Como possa fazer uma função para inserir os dados login, nome e valor em minha lista?

```
typedef struct registro_st{         // sequência de objetos do mesmo tipo
    char login[50];
    char nome[50];
    float valor;
    struct registro *prox;
} registro;

typedef struct nodo_st{
    registro dado;
    struct nodo *prox;
} nodo;

typedef struct Lista_st{
    nodo *cabeca;
    nodo *cauda;
    int tamanho;
} lista;


nodo* CriarNodo(registro p){

    nodo* n;
    n = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    n->dados = p;
    n->prox= NULL;
    return n;
}

lista* criarLista(){
    lista* l = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    l->cabeca = NULL;
    l->cauda = NULL;
    l->tamanho = 0;
    return l;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça suas leituras de input no main, crie no main um registro novo (você não colocou a função criaRegistro, logo assumi que ainda não a implementou). Após ler os dados, coloque dessa forma no registro, nó e , consequentemente, na lista:

```
int main() {
    .
    .
    .
    registro_st *novoRegistro = criaRegistro(); //é importante fazer essa função!
    printf("Login: ");
    scanf("%s", novorRegistro->login);
    printf("Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", novorRegistro->nome);
    printf("Valor: ");
    scanf("%f", novorRegistro->valor);
    nodo_st *novoNodo = criaNodo(novoRegistro);
    inserirLista(novoNodo);
    .
    .
    .
    }
```